# mediaelement.js -> bigger buttons?

Tags: css, button, video, fullscreen, mediaelement.js

I'm trying to make the controlbar bigger for ipad/android. Especially the fullscreen
button. When changing the css it's bigger but work functioning for the whole rectangle e.g.
Any ideas?

ciao Valentijn

Answer (score 0):

this solution is css only.

i simply resized the all elements inside a media query, also the buttons css sprites/background images by simply adjusting the background-size and background-position properties.

the following styles are for the play, pause, fullscreen and unfullscreen buttons only, but you get the point and should be able to complete the missing buttons.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1824px) {

  .mejs-container .mejs-controls {
    height: 60px;
  }
    .mejs-container .mejs-controls div {
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
    } 
    .mejs-controls .mejs-time-rail span {
      height: 40px;
    }    
    .mejs-container .mejs-controls .mejs-time {
      height: 40px;
    }    
      .mejs-container .mejs-controls .mejs-time span {
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 40px;
      }    
    .mejs-controls .mejs-button button {
      width: 46px;
      height: 46px;
      background-size: 400px;
    }    
      .mejs-controls .mejs-play button {
      }    
      .mejs-controls .mejs-pause button {
        background-position: 0 -44px;
      }    
      .mejs-controls .mejs-fullscreen-button button {
        background-position: -90px 0;
      }    
      .mejs-controls .mejs-unfullscreen button {
        background-position: -90px -44px;
      }
}
```